# databound datagridviewcheckbox not updating underlying list until focus changed

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am using a winform datagridview bound to a list. There is a checkbox column bound to a Boolean type field. The problem is, when check/uncheck a checkbox, its not updating the underlying list until I change focus to another cell of the datagrid view.

Is there any way to do it by not changing focus to another cell?

Comment: There is no such property for datagridview.

Comment: My bad, delved too much into `wpf` recently.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` class addresses that specifically.  You should have already read it.  It should have been the first thing you did when you knew that you wanted to know something about that type.